# Un attacco "imminente'

Tags: word-meaning

L'altra sera parlando dei ben noti e tristi fatti di Manchester, Barbara Serra annunciava in diretta a Bianca Berlinguer che il livello di guardia in Inghilterra era stato appena alzato al massimo grado, il che stava a significare un attacco imminente. L'uso dell'aggettivo "imminente" ha creato ovviamente molta preoccupazione e  qualche incomprensione.

Barbara Serra traduceva letteralmente dall'inglese "[imminent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/imminent)" che come riportano i dizionari sta a significare "molto probabile che accada , e in tempi brevi", mentre l'italiano [imminente](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=imminente) significa "che accadrà, e in tempi brevi".

Concordate sul significato di imminente in italiano, oppure viene anche da noi usato per indicare una probabilità alta, ma non certa?

Comment: Non so che dizionario usi Barbara Serra. Quelli consultati da me dicono diversamente.

Comment: Il senso non è “molto probabile che accada”, bensì, semmai, “molto probabile che accada presto, da un momento all'altro”. In inglese non diresti che un'eclissi di sole del 2050 è *imminent*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns mainly the meaning of an English word, perhaps misunderstood by the OP.

Comment: @DaG - ma hai letto la mia domanda, almeno? Capisco che chiudere sia più facile che rispondere, però.....

Comment: Certo, se no come avrei fatto a commentarla? È impossibile rispondere nella sua forma corrente: come dire «*cheese* vuol dire “prosciutto”; secondo voi in italiano “formaggio” vuol dire “prosciutto”»? (Esagero, e prendila nel senso amichevole in cui lo scrivo, ma spero che la mia obiezione sia chiara.)

Comment: @DaG - come sospettavo, non l'hai capita.

Comment: Può darsi. Abbi la bontà di riformularla in modo che possa capirla anch'io, allora.

Comment: @DaG - se e' vero che non la capisci (dubito) allora devi chiudere come "unclear what you are asking". Non sto chiedendo cosa imminent voglia dire in inglese, quello l'ho detto io chiaramente nella  Domanda!! Sto chiedendo se in italiano abbia un significato diverso, più preciso. In fondo etimologicamente  hanno la stessa origine.

Comment: Io credo di averla capita: sei tu che affermi che non la capisco. Il problema è che c'è qualche dubbio sulla tua interpretazione del significato del termine inglese *imminent* (cf. il mio primo commento qui sopra, la risposta di egreg e i miei commenti alla risposta). A conferma che – *de facto* pur se non nelle intenzioni – la tua domanda verte sulla parola inglese, puoi notare che la circostanziata risposta di egreg si riferisce per lo più all'inglese (cita tre dizionari di inglese e solo uno monolingue italiano).

Comment: @DaG - mmm..ho postato la definizione di 4 diversi affidabili dizionari inglesi, e l'uso fatto dalla British Intelligence  ne conferma il significato. In inglese significa "molto probablile" mentre in italiano significa "certo". Il termine inglese e' un pretesto per chiedere se anche in italiano il senso possa essere ambiguo o no. Domanda illecita?

Comment: Ho tolto il voto di chiusura, ma le perplessità che esprimo qui sopra rimangono.

Comment: Posso suggerire di sostituire, nella tua domanda, "molto probabile che accada " con “molto probabile che accada, e in tempi brevi” (in analogia alla tua definizione per l'italiano), così è chiaro che la tua domanda si riferisce esclusivamente al grado di probabilità (se ho capito bene)?

Comment: @abarisone -  non so se hai fatto bene a riesumare questa vecchia domanda che, come avrai visto, ha generato solo inutili diatribe.

Answer (score 2):

Il mio dizionario di inglese (OED) dà, per *imminent*,

> about to happen

e, come senso arcaico, “overhanging”.

Quindi lo stesso che in italiano. Ecco la [voce del Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/imminente)

> **imminènte** agg. [dal lat. *immĭnens -entis*, part. pres. di *imminere* «sovrastare», comp. di *in-*<sup>1</sup> e *minere* «sporgere»]. – 1. letter. Che sporge o è sospeso sopra qualcuno o qualche cosa; sovrastante: la rupe i.; sotto l’i. luna; la spada i. sopra il capo di Damocle; fra’ cedri al suo talamo imminenti (Foscolo). 2. Più com. in senso fig., che è prossimo ad accadere o a esser fatto: il pericolo era i.; l’arrivo sembrava i.; libro d’i. pubblicazione.

A conferma, la traduzione del [Sansoni](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Inglese/I/imminent.shtml):

> agg.
>   1 imminente, vicino, prossimo: war is imminent la guerra è imminente.
>   2 (ant) (overhanging) imminente, minaccioso: imminent danger pericolo imminente.

Il [Picchi (Hoepli)](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Inglese-Italiano/I/imminent.php?lingua=en) dà “imminente, prossimo, incombente”.

Comment: The meaning in English is not so clear-cut :  imminent : coming, likely to happen very soon http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/imminent - likely or certain to happen very soon - http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/imminent - If you say that something is imminent, especially something unpleasant, you mean it is almost certain to happen very soon. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/imminent

Comment: This ambiguous meaning  actually fits the meaning  of the warning.."an imminent attack" from the British Intelligence. But "un attacco imminente" has a more precise meaning in my opinion....or not?

Comment: @Gio, potresti chiarire un po' meglio in che senso “coming, likely to happen very soon” sarebbe diverso dall'italiano “imminente”?

Comment: Per aggiungere una tesserina all'ottima risposta, il significato qui pertinente (cioè a parte *overhanging* etc.) dell'OED completo è “Of an event, etc. (almost always of evil or danger): Impending threateningly, hanging over one's head; ready to befall or overtake one; close at hand in its incidence; coming on shortly”, che mi sembra si adatti esattamente al senso dell'italiano “imminente”

Comment: @Gio Non riesco a vedere dove ci sia l'ambiguità. I dizionari che citi dicono le stesse cose; un •attacco imminente* è essenzialmente certo (come un *imminent attack*), ma non se ne conosce il momento e forse ci dà il tempo di controbatterlo.

Comment: @egreg - no, le definizioni in inglese parlano di alta probabilità, non solo di  certezza. MacMillan molto chiaramente dice "likely or certain to happen". In italiano mi sembra che non sia una questione di "se e quando" , ma solo di "quando".

Comment: @Gio Sbagli su come interpretare l'italiano *imminente*: non dimenticare il senso figurato.